# What do you call a tristate when there are only two states?

Tags: word-choice, prefixes

In programming the word "tristate" is used quite often to indicate an object with three possible states. A checkbox is a good example, it can be checked, unchecked or it can have no value yet.

I now have to describe two objects in the same context where the first has three states and the second only has two.

I considered using "duostate" for the latter, but google doesn't seem to know the word. And "dualstate" also seems to be incorrect.

So what word could I use to describe an object with two possible states?

Edit: To clarify, the first object has states called In Range, Extended Range and Out of Range and the second only has In Range and Out of Range. I'm trying to write a piece of documentation which describes functions that convert a digit (0, 1 or 2 in this case) to "In Range", "Extended Range" and "Out of Range". There are two functions, one converts the digit to a digital/duo/dual state and the other to the tristate. So, I'm trying to find the right word to describe the first function.

Comment: That word seems more related to States in the U.S., not as much to the state or form an object is in

Comment: Binary; toggle; perhaps even switch...

Comment: Ah, "binary state" could work, thank you

Comment: As an off-topic side note: "how do you call" is what you say in Dutch, Russian, or French, but in English it's "what do you call".

Comment: *boolean* is what unequivocally implies two states.

Comment: I'd call it a *flag*.

Comment: @RegDwigнt, you caught me, thanks for the correction. Your first "guess" was actually accurate, I'm dutch.

Comment: @ArmenԾիրունյան *Boolean* is what unequivocally implies a truth value upon which one can do Boolean arithmetic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Toggle* is used of both objects with a representation (such as a checkbox that doesn't accept an indeterminate state, or a button with a "pressed" and "unpressed" state) and also of programming objects that wrap a boolean so as to represent such a binary state.

To describe the state itself, *binary* would be more appropriate.

*Boolean* is sometimes misused for this, because the binary state would tend to be dealt with as a Boolean value and in terms of computer science *binary* is very more often used in the sense of the binary number system. However, *Boolean* refers to truth values upon which one can do Boolean arithmetic, while one certainly can do Boolean arithmetic on binary states that is not a feature of the binary state itself.